# CGAffineTransform scaling subviews issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-interface

Is there an easy way to tell CGAffineTransform not to scale frames of the subviews of a scaled view? view.autoResizeMask = false doesn't seem to work in this case. The only thing that is kinda "working" is reversing the transformation for subviews, like

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    (subview as! UIView).transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(view.transform)
}
```

However, this takes 10 times longer in terms of computational time and is not quiet flexible. Does somebody know any other more efficient way, to scale the origins of the frames, but no their bounds ?

Comment: What is the visual effect that you are trying to achieve by scaling a superview while keeping subviews as they are?

Comment: The views are arranged in circle. I have a pinch gesture recognizer, so that when I pinch I scale the circle, and the views move further from the center. However, I don't want them to become bigger as a result of this scaling.

Comment: Is the circle you're scaling visible, or is used only to arrange the other views?

Comment: the circle is not visible, however it consists of 500 hundred points, so I need to scale all of them.

Comment: Why do you need to scale the points? It sounds like what you're trying to do is move views outward, as if they were on the perimeter of an expanding circle. Is that your goal? If so, you don't need any points on a circle, you just need to do a little math, and move the origin of your views. You should edit your question to include more detail on what you're trying to accomplish; using a transform might not be the best way to go.

Comment: Ok I see it, thank you I think that transform is just not the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, that's just how transforms work.  It sounds like you might be better off with a design that doesn't scale the superview, although you solution of scaling back up the subviews is pretty clever. :)

You could at least always cache the inverted transform to save a bit of computation:

```
let inverse = CGAffineTransformInvert( view.transform )
for subview in view.subviews {
   (subview as! UIView).transform = inverse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The views are arranged in circle. I have a pinch gesture recognizer, so that when I pinch I scale the circle, and the views move further from the center. However, I don't want them to become bigger as a result of this scaling.

Well, there's your problem. You were just being lazy with your scaling transform. As the pinch gesture proceeds, you need to actually do the work of enlarging the circle and repositioning the views.